# Index Error: invalid index to scalar variable

Tags: python-3.x, list, point-clouds

I am trying to create bounding box using dimensions mentioned in the detection annotation in [this](http://www2.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/%7Espinello/pcloud-dataset.html) dataset (I am using the polyterrasse one) for some reason the following code works for 25 frames and then suddenly it gives me an error :

```css
IndexError: invalid index to scalar variable.
```

```css
frame_path=glob.glob("path/to/pointcloud/folder/*.ezd")
bbox_path= glob.glob("path/to/detection/annotation/folder/*.ezd.bbox")
bbox=[]
cbox_dim=[]

for i in range(len(bbox_path)):
  #convert the frame into pcd format and then load via PCL 
  bbox=np.loadtxt(bbox_path[i], dtype=np.float32)  # load tracklets for the frame
    if bbox.size==0:
        continue
    cbox_dim=np.asarray(bbox)
    pc= pcl.PointCloud() #create pointcloud
    pc.from_array(obj) #load frame into the point cloud

    clipper=pc.make_cropbox()
    for j in range(len(cbox_dim)):
        tx = cbox_dim[j][0] #Error occurs: Invalid index to scalar variable 
        ty = cbox_dim[j][1]
        tz = cbox_dim[j][2]
        
        #similarly set rotation and dimensions
```

What are the possible reasons for this?

Comment: Looks like `cbox_dim` has only 1 dimension, so `cbox_dim[j]` is a scalar that is a single value.

Comment: cropbox is 3D just like a bounding box. What confuses me is that this program is working for 25 frames and then it gives an error. I am getting the right objects cut out of frames and without any issues. I checked the 26th frame and it looks just the same in terms of data and format. But I am getting an indexing issue.

Comment: Then probably you should check `bbox_path[25]` because in this case `bbox=np.loadtxt(...)` gives you 1D data.

Comment: The text files contain nx10 arrays as data. Each row in these arrays represents the centroid and dimensions of the bounding box. That is why I used np.load text to take that data in directly as a numpy array.

Comment: I have made necessary changes in the global paths. Hope this makes things easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I downloaded the data, unpacked it, checked it and it turned out that file `polyterrasse026.ezd.bbox` has only 1 row of data:

```
1.718750 5.066964 -0.327395 0.693458 0.684387 1.325830 0 0 0 0
```

That is why `bbox_path[26]` is 1D array. This is the reason you got the error.

EDIT.

To verify if `bbox` is 2D array you may use, for example, `bbox.ndim == 2`. `bbox.size` shows the number of elements in the array not the number of dimensions.

The nature of your problem is that `np.loadtxt()` returns 1D array if file contains only one row of data. You may handle this problem like this:

```
if bbox.ndim == 1:
    bbox = np.array([bbox])
```

Comment: Yes it varies a lot in terms of the number of rows each file has. But this is why I am checking for length of the array before accessing the data. So whatever nx10 array it has, the program goes through iterations  until n and accesses the data accordingly. Am I getting the logic wrong here?

Comment: @kav You check the condition `bbox.size==0` which does not guarantee that `bbox` is 2D array

Comment: the checking I was implying was  `for j in range (len(cbox_dim)) ` which should be able to work even for one iteration if I am not mistaken?

Comment: @kav Again, you get the error because `cbox_dim` should be 2D array but it is 1D array. When it is 2D array you iterate over rows (1D arrays), when it is 1D array you iterate over values (0D arrays). So for loop works as expected and does not check the number of dimensions in `cbox_dim`. The fix for the problem is provided in the EDIT part of my answer. Check it out please.

Comment: It worked ! Thanks! I have one more question for you. I have dealing with another issue with this dataset as I try to cur out the instances using the cropbox filter but for some reason, I am able to do that only after frame 1. Can you please let me know if you are having the sam eissue? Shall I edit my question and add my next problem into it? I am relatively new to stackoverflow so I am not sure if I should ask a separate question or edit this one.

Comment: @kav I cannot run the code you provided in the question since the code does not have imports. So I don't know what is `pcl`. Better start a new question and explain the new problem you encountered.